Problem installing .NET SDK in Visual Studio Code
I'm trying to use C# in VS Code which requires me to install the .NET SDK.
I'm following the steps provided by VS Code to install it, but it doesn't work, even after reinstalling it does not work.
Screenshot #1
Screenshot #2
A few things that I've tried:

Repairing Microsoft redistribution
Reconfigure environment path
Reinstall VS Code
Trying older versions


Hi Ahmad, Can you please provide details about your Issue?  Do you get any error messages on VS when you try to run the .Net application?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

here are some things to try or check

have you installed the c# extension(dev kit) by Microsoft for your vs code
you can try downloading and installing it directly from netsdkdownload

